# Vs code поиск используемого функционала

Tags: javascript, reactjs, функции, visual-studio-code, поиск

Есть у меня в проекте например функция `const foo = (arg:number)=>arg`

Проект большой,есть ли какое-то умное расширение чтобы найти где используется именно эта функция?
Раньше делал поиск по названию функции,естественно поиск выдал кучу результатов (тк название функции лежащей в утилитах конкретного компонента может совпадать с кучей других названий в разных утилитах)

Не обязательно про vs code,может есть другие редакторы позволяющие это сделать.

Comment: WebStorm или Intellij IDEA(ultimate) От jetBrains позволяет это делать. ctrl зажимаешь и на функцию тыкаешь, показывает, где именно она юзается.

Comment: @SwaD спасибо,выручил!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

WebStorm или Intellij IDEA(ultimate) От jetBrains позволяет это делать.

ctrl зажимаешь и на функцию тыкаешь, показывает, где именно она используется.

Comment: в vsCode тоже самое. И не только с функциями это работает.